# javascript : how to change "this" scope on an event

Tags: javascript, this

I've opened MDN documentation about Function.prototype.bind, but my scripts still not work.

i want the `this` refers to the htmlElement that added to addEventListener. The problem is, why my `this` refers to object window.

here is the scripts without bind (http://jsbin.com/ejimor/1/edit) :

```
var handle1 = document.getElementById('handle1'),
    handle2 = document.getElementById('handle2');

function doLogin() {
    alert(this);
}

function enterForm(ev) {
    if ( ev.which === 13 ) {
        doLogin();
    }
}

handle1.addEventListener('click', doLogin, false);
// this alert: [object HTMLButtonElement] this is what i want


handle2.addEventListener('keyup', enterForm, false);
// this alert: [object Window] this is what i do not want
```

So, how to solve this?

Comment: How did you try using `bind`?

Comment: Easiest solution is just to pass either `ev` or `this` in your call: `doLogin(ev);`. Or you can explicitly set the receiver using `call` or `apply`, but that's overcomplicating the simple matter.

Comment: Also, you appear to want to handle a form’s submission in both possible ways; why not handle the `submit` event once?

Comment: :D thankyou @minitech , i never use `<form>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is that you want to call `doLogin` in the context in which `enterForm` is called - for that you can use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
function enterForm(ev) {
    if (ev.which === 13) doLogin.call(this);
}
```

`call` and `apply` ensure that `this` inside of the function they are called on is set to the first argument that is passed to them (so we could call `doLogin.call({x: 1})` and get an alert of `[object Object]`, for example).

If you always want `doLogin` to be called in the context of your `HTMLButtonElement` then you can replace the function with a bound version of the same function by using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
function doLogin() { alert(this); }
doLogin = doLogin.bind(handle1);
```

`bind` creates a new version of the function it is called on, with the `this` permanently bound to the first argument passed to it.  So, in the same vein, if we did this:

```
var newLogin = doLogin.bind({x: 1});
```

every time we called `newLogin` it will be called with its `this` context set to our anonymous `{x: 1}` object (even if we did `newLogin.call(12)` or `newLogin.apply(someObject)`)